# Parsing an List of Abstract objects of POJOS

Tags: java, gson

I want to parse, with Gson's help, a list of abstract objects:

```
List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>
```

Until now, I only had to parse Lists of objects, so when I had to declare it's type I used:

```
 new TypeToken<List<myObjectDto>>() {}.getType());
```

But in this case, I don't understand how I should declare this type in my `Gson.fromJson` method.

Comment: [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is an interface. It is not an abstract class.

Comment: Oh my goodness, you're right @Lutz Horn.

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: How to create the (java object) Type of this List of object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to put your new `List` inside `TypeToken`:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<List<Pair<Integer, Integer>>>() {}.getType();
List<Pair<Integer, Integer>> yourList = gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
```

Comment: Oh, my... How could I not see that -_-' Thanks a lot for this answer, I edited because of a little mistake. Thanks again @MikO

Comment: No problem @Fabinout, we're here to help! And thanks for the edit, but I have edited again, because you shouldn't put a comment *"Edited by Fabinout to change ..."*. When your edit is approved, it's visible that you have edited and exactly what you changed, so the comment is redundant info and makes the posts longer...

Comment: Yeah, it didn't accept any edition shorter than 6 characters long. Have a nice day